# Correct binding for dropdown menu from ObservableCollection and get its index

Tags: c#, wpf

Variations of this question seems to be quite common, but I have yet to find a solution that works for me. I am attempting to place a Dropdown menu within a Button.ContextMenu, using an Observable collection, and thought I was on the right track, with one piece missing: I have yet to be able to get the index of the item selected, and although I can see my collection in the debugger, I am beginning to wonder if the items are really getting found, will explain as I go. First, the XAML...you can see that I have a binding for the Button Content, and the idea is that after a menu item gets selected, my code behind will update that property. Which it could, if I could get the index of the collection that is being collected:

```xml
    <Button x:Name="DeviceSelMenuButton" Content="{Binding DeviceID_and_SN, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="25,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" FontSize="14" Click="DeviceSelMenuButton_Click">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceID_SN_Collection, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="true"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

As you can imagine, I have tried many variations for the CommandParameter bindings, but with this one I can at least see some things in my ICommand method. The thing that troubles me is that at the first push of the button (and no there are no errors in the Output window regarding the bindings), under the ContextMenu cm's Items property, I see a legitimate items label under items.CurrentItem, and item.CurrentPosition is 0 -- which at first looked promising, was hoping I could use that as the index, until I realized I was looking at the last item and so it must be meaningless. After that, the second time, and all subsequent pushes of the button, the items.CurrentItem is null, and the items.Current position is 0xffffffff. Pasting in the relevant pieces of code, starting with the class defining the collection, ICommand, etc:

```
class CustomDeviceGUI : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Declare the event 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { }; 
    private string _deviceDisplayString;
    private ICommand UpdateMenuICommand; 
    List<string> ControllerDeviceList = new List<string>();

    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> _DeviceID_SN_Collection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();

    // CTOR
    public CustomDeviceGUI()
    {
        ControllerDeviceList.Add("CustomDevice Device 1");
        ControllerDeviceList.Add("CustomDevice Device 2");
        ControllerDeviceList.Add("CustomDevice Device 3");
        ControllerDeviceList.Add("CustomDevice Device 6");
        UpdateDeviceID(3);  // TODO Get from GUI!!!
    }

    #region CustomDeviceGUI Properties

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> DeviceID_SN_Collection
    {
        get
        {
            _DeviceID_SN_Collection.Clear();
            foreach (string str in ControllerDeviceList)
            {
                _DeviceID_SN_Collection.Add(str);
            }
            return _DeviceID_SN_Collection;
        }
        private set 
        {
            _DeviceID_SN_Collection = value;
        }
    }

    public string DeviceID_and_SN
    {
        get
        {
            return _deviceDisplayString;
        }
        private set
        {
            _deviceDisplayString = value;
        }
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (UpdateMenuICommand == null)
                UpdateMenuICommand = new MyGuiCommand();

            return UpdateMenuICommand;
        }
        set
        {
            UpdateMenuICommand = value;
            RaisePropertyChangeEvent("MyCommand");  // ????
        }
    }

    public void UpdateDeviceID(int deviceID)
    {
        this._deviceDisplayString = ControllerDeviceList[deviceID];
        RaisePropertyChangeEvent("DeviceID_and_SN");
        RaisePropertyChangeEvent("DeviceID_SN_Collection");    
    }

    public class MyGuiCommand : ICommand
    {
        // Two events are kicked off when the command is executed
        public static event UpdateDeviceSelectedEventHandler UpdateDeviceSelectedEvent;

        // defining signature for any event handlers for the events we create here
        public delegate void UpdateDeviceSelectedEventHandler(int deviceIndex); 

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ContextMenu cm = (ContextMenu)parameter;
            var itemSource = cm.ItemsSource;
            var itemBG = cm.ItemBindingGroup;
            var items = cm.Items;

            UpdateDeviceSelectedEvent(1); // TODO parameter with index from GUI    
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged // was ;
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
    }
} // class CustomDeviceGUI
```

and finally the relevant code from MainWindow.xaml.cs, not a lot happening here:

```
    // register for the event from the ICommand.Execute
    WpfBindingAttempts.CustomDeviceGUI.MyGuiCommand.UpdateDeviceSelectedEvent += new WpfBindingAttempts.CustomDeviceGUI.MyGuiCommand.UpdateDeviceSelectedEventHandler(UpdateDeviceSelectedAfterSwitch);

    // Handles event that occurs when a different device is selected
    //    via the dropdown menu -- sets the active device, and updates its ID/SN
    void UpdateDeviceSelectedAfterSwitch(int deviceIndex)
    {
         _customDeviceGui.UpdateDeviceID(deviceIndex);
    }
```

code behind for button:

```
    private void DeviceSelMenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // " (sender as Button)" is PlacementTarget
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as Button);
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
        (sender as Button).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Think that's everything. Any help is greatly appreciated. If this looks familiar, it is. I got over the first hurdles and slammed into this brick wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any direct way to return the selected index of an item within a `ContextMenu`.  I don't believe the `CurrentItem` property holds anything to do with which item has been selected.  I'm not sure exactly what this property does do (it might be something used internally by the framework), but I would recommend that you ignore it.

Instead of making the context menu be the `CommandParameter`, make the items in your collection the `CommandParameter`s.  To do this, change the `CommandParameter` setter to the following:

```xml
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
```

Then, pass the list of all devices to your `MyGuiCommand`, in a constructor argument for example.  Finally, in your `Execute` method, search within this list of devices to find the selected device, which will be in the `parameter`.